# RegEx match content inside div with specific class

Tags: html, regex

How can I match the contents of all divs that have a specific class. For example:

```
  <div class="column-box-description paddingT05">content</div>
```

Comment: What is it that you're really trying to do? (Hint: regular expressions are (almost always) a *terrible* solution to parsing an irregular language such as HTML).

Comment: I want to replace the contents inside the divs with php variables. The content inside the divs is only text

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't do this with regex unless you can make strong assumptions about the text you're matching; you'll do better with something that actually parses HTML.

But, if you can make these stronger assumptions, you can use:

```
<div class="[^"]*?paddingT05[^"]*?">(.*?)<\/div>
```

The key part is the reluctant quantifier `*?` which matches the minimal text possible (i.e. it doesn't greedily eat up the `</div>`.

Comment: @FlorianShena That is not sufficient feedback to be able to help you. Here's a [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gY2j4ObcC-yoK-XG)

Comment: The reason is not working is because it doesn't match new line inside the div.

Comment: @FlorianShena that is a configuration problem. You need to enable multiline regexes, which are not usually enabled by default. You should have noted this in your question. Additionally, you have not specified which tools you are using to do the replacement. In the future, provide this information in your question if you expect the answers to be able to meet these requirements.

Comment: For now I am not using a specific tool I am just trying to find a correct RegEx. I have selected the multiline flag.
http://regexr.com/38l1f

Comment: @FlorianShena PCRE, with multiline [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/14nM35RAzQgprHoO). I have a feeling it's your tester that's failing, not the regex.

Comment: @FlorianShena `.` doesn't match newlines by default; use the `s` option to enable this. (not `m`), or use `(.|\n)*?` instead of `.*?`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
<div.*class\s*=\s*["'].*the_class_you_require_here.*["']\s*>(.*)<\/div>
```

Replace "the_class_you_require_here" with a class name of your choosing. The div content is in the first group resulted from this expesion. You can read on groups here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html