# How to capture the actual html tag content using regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Given the following example code:

```
bla bla 
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">beta</div> 
    bla bla bla 
    <div class="c">charlie</div> 
    <b>bold</b> 
    etc ... 
</div>
```

How do I extract the content of the tag `<div class="a">`. Please note there are an unknown number of similar tags nested inside the parent tag. A simple regex like:

```
<div class="a">(.*?)</div>
```

does not work because it will return:

```
<div class="b">beta
```

instead of the actual contents of the tag.

The regex should somehow count the number of opening and closing div tags to determine where to stop. I am not sure this is even possible in regex hence my question.

**Update:** My question is not on how to extract a tags data by regex in general. My question is how to make sure all tag contents is extracted (like a html parser).

Comment: Maybe you want to use a HTML parser instead. See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/3895469).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match content inside div with specific class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743495/regex-match-content-inside-div-with-specific-class)

Comment: @oddRaven This would probably be the best option. However unfortunately coldfusion 9 does not contain an html parser.

Comment: @Mistalis my question has little simularity with this other question.

Comment: I think you need recursive regex for what you want. Does coldfusion support it ?

Comment: @Gawil Coldfusion is based on Java. As far as I know java does not support this, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Wait, the `div`s are nested here. You cannot use a regex then.

Comment: You're right, Java does not support recursion... So coldfusion shouldn't either I guess. I can't see any other way to do what you want with regex, sorry...

Comment: I hope [this article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/779-parsing-html-tag-data-into-a-coldfusion-structure.htm) will be of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for pointing that article out. I actually read this article before posting my question here. The regex used does not account for nested similar tags.

Comment: _(like a html parser)_ well just use an HTML parser. That's what they are designed for. A good one that is open source is [jSoup](https://jsoup.org/). And here is an article from Ben Nadel on using it with ColdFusion - [Parsing, Traversing, And Mutating HTML With ColdFusion And jSoup](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-parsing-traversing-and-mutating-html-with-coldfusion-and-jsoup.htm).

Comment: I also highly recommend jsoup over regex when it comes to dealing with HTML... (I'm referenced in Ben Nadel's article.)  It will auto-correct/normalize incorrectly nested HTML and you have a lot more control over it.  You can remove sub-elements, identify images/URLs/headers/anything, remove styles, add classes, sanitize, inject HTML blocks, etc.  Finding "div.a" in an HTML document is similar to jQuery: "fragment = myHTML.select('div.a').first().toString();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to fully parse html with normal regex without some extensions.

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

With that said, you could parse the html yourself or use something like jSoup.

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-parsing-traversing-and-mutating-html-with-coldfusion-and-jsoup.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not is more or less the same question I have I installed Jsoup as you, Miguel-F and James Moberg suggested and it works pretty well.